# Absolute value of $1$ in PlotLegends in ComplexPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

When using `PlotLegends -> "Automatic"` in `ComplexPlot`, it seems that Mathematica always picks some value different from 1 on the absolute value bar. See here (it picked the value 1.3):

```
ComplexPlot[z, {z, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Is there a way I can make the value 1 appear on the absolute value bar instead (for any given plot when the function attains 1 in absolute value)? I couldn't find it in the official documentation of `ComplexPlot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `ComplexPlot`, it seems that the ticks are hardcoded in `` System`ComplexPlotsDump`parseShadingLegend ``, and cannot be *easily and reliably* changed by user. You can request the feature to the [Wolfram Technical Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).

However, let's break down how Mathematica picks the value anyway. It turns out that the automatically chosen value is the $97.5 \%$ percentile of acquired absolute values of the function on the given domain* (calculated in `` System`ComplexPlotsDump`complexPlotRasterGenerate ``).

```
f[z_] := z;

domainGrid = 
  Catenate@Table[
    x + y I, {x, Subdivide[-1, 1, 144]}, {y, Subdivide[-1, 1, 144]}];
values = f /@ domainGrid;

Quantile[Flatten @ Abs @ values, 0.975] // N
(* 1.26785 *)

System`ComplexPlotsDump`makeNiceNumber[%]
(* 1.3 *)
```

Without patching the source code, we can modify the ticks with this auxiliary function:

```
changeLegendTicks[vals_] := 
 Function[cPlot, 
  cPlot /. {t1_, t2 : {p1_, v1_?NumberQ | NumberForm[v1_, __]}, 
     t3_} :> {t1, Sequence @@ ({Rescale[#, {0, v1}, {t1[[1]], p1}], #} & /@ vals), t3}]

plot = ComplexPlot[z, {z, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 200];

Row[{
  plot, "     ",
  plot // changeLegendTicks[{0.1, 0.5, 1}]
  }]
```

[image: ComplexPlot]

Note that this is a **"hacky way"**, and you should always check that the position of changed ticks is sensible.

---

*Domain is discretized into a grid with size `RasterSize` (144 by default, or 77 if `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`, or whatever the user sets).

Comment: @Vestoo In your request to Wolfram Tech Support ask that `ComplexPlot` support the `OpacityFunction` and `OpactityFunctionScaling` options similar to `DensityPlot3D` support of these options.